# How could I stop ssh offering a wrong key?

Tags: ssh, gitolite, identity-management

(This is a problem with ssh, not gitolite)

I've configured gitolite on my home server (ubuntu 12.04 server, open-ssh). I want an special identityfile to administer the repositories, so I need to access throught ssh to my own host ussing two different identity keys.

This is the content of my .ssh/config file:

```
Host gitadmin.gammu.com
User            git
IdentityFile    /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_gitolite_mantra

Host git.gammu.com
User            git
IdentityFile    /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra
```

This is the content of my hosts file:

```
# Git
127.0.0.1      gitadmin.gammu.com
127.0.0.1      git.gammu.com
```

So I should be able to communicate with gitolite this way to access with the "normal" account:

```
$ssh git.gammu.com
```

and this way to access with the administrative account:

```
$ssh gitadmin.gammu.com
```

When I try to access with the normal account, all is ok:

```
alvaro@mantra:~/.ssh$ ssh git.gammu.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello alvaro, this is gitolite 2.2-1 (Debian) running on git 1.7.9.5
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
    @R_ @W_    testing
Connection to git.gammu.com closed.
```

When I do the same with the administrative account:

```
alvaro@mantra:~$ ssh gitadmin.gammu.com
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello alvaro, this is gitolite 2.2-1 (Debian) running on git 1.7.9.5
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
    @R_ @W_    testing
Connection to gitadmin.gammu.com closed.
```

It should show the administrative repository. If I launch ssh with verbose option:

```
ssh -vvv gitadmin.gammu.com 
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra (0x7f7cb6c0fbc0)
debug2: key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_gitolite_mantra (0x7f7cb6c044d0)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
...
```

**It's offering the key id_alvaro_mantra, and it shouldn't!!**

The same happens when I specify the key with the -i option:

```
ssh -i /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_gitolite_mantra -vvv gitadmin.gammu.com
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra (0x7fa365237f90)
debug2: key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_gitolite_mantra (0x7fa365230550)
debug2: key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_gitolite_mantra (0x7fa365231050)
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 36:b1:43:36:af:4f:00:e5:e1:39:50:7e:07:80:14:26
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 36:b1:43:36:af:4f:00:e5:e1:39:50:7e:07:80:14:26
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
...
```

What's happening?  I'm missing something, but I can't find what.

These are the contents of my home dir:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 alvaro alvaro  395 nov 14 18:00 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r--  1 alvaro alvaro  326 nov 21 10:21 config
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro  137 nov 20 20:26 environment
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1766 nov 20 21:41 id_alvaromaceda.es
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  404 nov 20 21:41 id_alvaromaceda.es.pub
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1766 nov 14 17:59 id_alvaro_mantra
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  395 nov 14 17:59 id_alvaro_mantra.pub
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro  771 nov 14 18:03 id_developer_mantra
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1679 nov 20 12:37 id_dos_pruebasgit
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  395 nov 20 12:37 id_dos_pruebasgit.pub
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1679 nov 20 12:46 id_gitolite_mantra
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  397 nov 20 12:46 id_gitolite_mantra.pub
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1675 nov 20 21:44 id_gitpruebas.es
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  408 nov 20 21:44 id_gitpruebas.es.pub
-rw-------  1 alvaro alvaro 1679 nov 20 12:34 id_uno_pruebasgit
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro  395 nov 20 12:34 id_uno_pruebasgit.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 alvaro alvaro 2434 nov 21 10:11 known_hosts
```

There are a bunch of other keys which aren't offered... why id_alvaro_mantra is offered and not the other keys? I can't understand.

I need some help, don't know where to look....

Answer (score 66, accepted):

This is expected behaviour according to the manpage of `ssh_config`:

```
 IdentityFile
         Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authentica‐
         tion identity is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for protocol
         version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for
         protocol version 2.  Additionally, any identities represented by the
         authentication agent will be used for authentication.  

         [...]

         It is possible to have multiple identity files specified in configu‐
         ration files; all these identities will be tried in sequence.  Mul‐
         tiple IdentityFile directives will add to the list of identities
         tried (this behaviour differs from that of other configuration
         directives).
```

Basically, specifying `IdentityFile`s just adds keys to a current list the SSH agent already presented to the client.

Try overriding this behaviour with this at the bottom of your `.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I'd completly forgotten ssh-agent!

Comment: Also, you can specify it on the host level, that's what I've done finally:
`Host git.gammu.com`
        `User                    git`
        IdentityFile    /home/alvaro/.ssh/id_alvaro_mantra
        IdentitiesOnly  yes`

Comment: @AlvaroMaceda is correct. Adding `IdentitiesOnly yes` to the gitadmin.gammu.com and git.gammu.com `Host` entries is enough. You don't have to make a wildcard entry that will affect other hosts.

Comment: Finally I found the solution, thanks! This should be enabled by default.

Comment: I found that the 'wrong' key was still offered regardless, and I _also_ needed to omit the problematic host from *, like `Host * !bitbucket.org`, per https://superuser.com/a/859719/73736

Answer (score 11):

For me the solution was to add a key to a list of ssh keys, with a command:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_name_of_my_rsa_key
```

so it could be offered when connecting to the server. After adding a ssh, it was automatically recognized the correct one.

**Edit:**

But recently I think the better solution, and more permanent one, is to go to `~/.ssh/config` and add `IdentitiesOnly yes` in your configuration file like this:

```
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
    User git
      IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Comment: Thank you, your second approach was exactly what I should do. Side notes: HostName is excessive in your example since its value equals Host's, indentation more than one level has no means since there's grouping by Host and Match in ssh_config only.

Comment: The second approach was the only one that worked for me on OS X Catalina.